# How can I modify and return a variable of type PChar in a function call

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I need store a variant value (which always return a string) in a PChar variable now i'm using this code

```
procedure VariantToPChar(v:variant; p : PChar);
Var
  s : String;      
begin
  s:=v;
  GetMem(p,Length(s)*Sizeof(Char));
  StrCopy(p, PChar(s));
end;
```

But i'm wondering if exist a better way

Comment: You can't possibly be using that code. It leaks memory, it doesn't produce any visible side effects for the caller (such as returning a newly allocated character buffer), and it doesn't null-terminate the string. Please copy and paste real code next time.

Comment: I think by "better way" he means "doesn't work at all - help!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: You really **shouldn't do this or use this code** as you're likely to encourage people to write code that leaks. People will call this and fail to free the memory since they don't know that this function allocates memory.

If you want to store something in a PChar size buffer, and have that value still be associated with p (the pointer p is modified and is different when you return from the procedure), then you need to make the parameter a `var`  (by-reference instead of by-value) parameter like this:

```
procedure AllocPCharBufFromVariant(v:variant; var p : PChar);
Var
  s : String;      
begin
  try
    s:=v;
    GetMem(p,(Length(s)+1)*Sizeof(Char)); // fixed to add 1 for the nul
    StrCopy(p, PChar(s));
  except
    on E:EVariantError do 
    begin
     p := nil;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I have also shown above handling EVariantError, which I have chosen to handle by returning nil in the p parameter, but you should think about how you want it to work, and then deal with it somehow.

The above code also leaks memory which is awful, so I renamed it AllocPChar. It seems like your original code has so many problems that I can't recommend a good way to do what looks like a giant pile of bad things and the name you chose is among the most awful choices.

At least the name Alloc gives me a hint so I'm thinking "I better free this when I'm done with it".

Comment: what about the null terminator?

Comment: @David You're right: you need to allocate p with `(length(s)+1)*sizeof(char)` to be able to hold the latest #0 in p.

Comment: I really hate this code because it leaks memory.  Almost nobody who is going to want this function is going to remember to free the memory block it returns a pointer to.

Answer (score 4):

Do you really, really have to create a PChar? As long as possible i would use Strings, and only if an external library (like the Windows API) requires a PChar, i would cast it.

```
uses
  Variants;
var
  vText: Variant;
  sText: String;
begin
  vText := 'Hello world';
  // VarToStr() can handle also null values
  sText := VarToStr(vText);
  // If absolutely necessary, cast it to PChar()
  CallToExternalFunction(PChar(sText));
```

Doing it like this you can avoid problems with memory (de)allocation, null values, and Ansi/Unicode chars. If the external function wants to write into the string, you can use `SetLength()` before casting. Maybe the article [Working with PChar](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/delphi/delphi.html#StringPChar) could give you some ideas.

Comment: If Ken came along he'd downvote you for not answering the question as posed.   There COULD conceivably be reasons to use a PChar, but you are right unless there is an explicit need to have a PChar buffer that is manually allocated.  Casting it is fine if you're sure that you don't need that pchar buffer value to have a lifetime longer than that string.

Comment: @Warren - Actually i **was** downvoted, but sometimes an answer that shows an easier way, is more helpful than the correct answer, i think. You are right, with the lifetime of the string, but this problem you have anyway. Whenever you allocate memory for a PChar, you can as well allocate the memory for a string (and use it as PChar). Sometime you have to free the memory for the PChar, that's how long the string should last.

Comment: @martinstoeckli - You're saying "avoids problems ... Ansi/Unicode chars". Unfortunately, this is not the case. Variants strings are WideStrings, so conversion to String or PChar is lossy. You'll get question marks if the string cannot be reproduced in the current code page. And this is more common than many people think.

Comment: @haimg - It depends on the Delphi version, if PChar means PAnsiChar or PWideChar. Current versions use two-byte WideChars and therefore wouldn't be lossy. With avoiding problems i referred particualarly to this change. In older Delphi versions, the code would produce a single-byte PAnsiChar and Delphi would call the corresponding windows api function `MessageBoxA()`. In newer versions the same code would produce a two byte PWideChar and Delphi would call `MessageBoxW()`. `SetLength()` will work in both cases, because it requires the count of characters, not bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect just a

```
PChar(string(v))
```

expression will do the trick.

And the memory used to store the converted string content will be available in the scope of this code (i.e. as long as the `string(v)` will be referenced - so you may want to use an explicit `string` variable to ensure that your `PChar` memory is still allocated).